# How to merge two columns of same name in sas dataset?

Tags: sas

I have a datafile having same column names. I want to merge them without any seperator and get it in new column.
But I am getting subsequent columns as var2 var3 var4 etc. How can we merge them in sas?

As I have columns of different variables with same name, for eg: my column order is name1, name2, name2,name1,name2 , we cant use var1,var2 for merging.
What can we do?

My csv datafile is similar to this
[image]

And my corresponding sasdata is
[image]

How can we get a merged column?(column name can be "EMPLOYMENT")

Comment: @Bendy         how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure I understand the question, but I think you want to use `cats()`. e.g. `newvar=cats(var1,var2,var3)`. This concatenates the values with no separators and no leading or trailing spaces.

`coalesce()` is another option that will take only the first nonmissing value in the list.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know the column number in prior. In this question, the variable 'I am employed in' can be in column 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,2,4,7,9 etc. Only thing we know is the column names are 'I am employed in'.


Is there any idea to cats the column who have word or phrase 'employ' comes in?!